# Is there a limit to how thin EM radiation can be spread out?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation

Sorry if this is completely off base but from my understanding, electromagnetic radiation, such as light, becomes less intense the further away it gets from the source. I assume the reduction of energy has to due with energy conservation given there are more locations the wave has to exist at. My question is, is there a limit to how "thin" the wave can be spread out? Is there a point in which the wave cannot be reduced any further (which would also mean the wave couldn't travel any further)? Or does the wave's intensity fade infinitely approaching but never reaching nonexistence.

Sorry if this is a dumb question, it probably is, i'm just curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As light spreads out the density of photons per area goes down. However the intensity can never drop below one photon. Hence we can see galaxies from billions of light years away.

Comment: So would it be correct to say that at some distance, there will be locations that light reaches, and other locations that light does not reach?

Comment: Yes, once you are sufficiently far away from a light source, photons don't come in a continuous stream. They could arrive anywhere assuming no obstructions but only have a probability of doing so. Imagine standing next to a machine gun that is spinning around out of control while continuously firing bullets. If you are very close you have a high chance of getting hit with many bullets per second. But if you are very very far away then there's just a small chance that any one bullet will ever hit you. The cool thing about light is that hot things shoot trillions of trillions of photons per sec

Comment: Hmm interesting. So theoretically if you were on a planet far enough away, you would be able to see a star from one location and then not be able to see it from another?

Comment: Theoretically yes but remember that observing a single photon wouldn't be something you would notice with the naked eye.

Comment: *"As light spreads out the density of photons per area goes down. However the intensity can never drop below one photon."* You seem to think of light as a stream of   small bodies (buckshot theory of light). Many experiments cannot be explained with this theory; EM theory of light is needed instead. In EM theory of light, classical or quantum, one works with Maxwell's equations and the intensity of retarded fields does decrease indefinitely with distance.